# How can we shorten a URL with Dynamic variable in SFMC using bitly

Tags: marketing-cloud, sms

I am trying to create an SMS message for customers to pass their last ordered number in a URL as a dynamic value so on click the customer will be redirected to the cart page. The entire URL looks very long and we would like to cut short it like bitly links.
As far I know bitly can cut short only static URLs but not the URLs with dynamic values.

Is there a way to cut short the URL that has dynamic value in it?

Answer (score 1):

Bitly does have an api that might attract some cost. This might help. https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023671752-Can-I-integrate-Bitly-with-Salesforce-